# A frame that is not completely distributive

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a frame, i.e., a complete lattice satisfying the infinite distributivity law $x\wedge \bigvee S=\bigvee \{x\wedge s\mid s\in S\}$. The totally below relation $x\lll y$ in $L$ means that if $y\le \bigvee S$, then $x\le s$ for some $s\in S$. It is well know that if $y= \bigvee \{x\in L\mid x\lll y\}$, then $L$ is completely distributive. An example of a frame that is not completely distributive is the lattice of regular open sets in $[0,1]$. However, in this lattice it is possible that $x\vee y=\top$ even if $x,y<\top$. What is an example of a frame that fails to be completely distributive due to $\bigvee \{x\in L \mid x\lll \top\}\ne \top$, in which $x\vee y=\top$ implies $x=\top$ or $y=\top$?

Comment: I think you can just add a new top element $\top'$ on top of $\top$. Then this new element is the top of your new lattice and, and $\top'$ is join irreducible.

Comment: @Average-user the problem is that then $\top '\lll \top '$, and thus the top element is the join of everything totally below it.

Comment: Right, so the "due to" fails, I didn't realize that this was what you wanted. But is not completely distributive lattice, I think that part is correct

Comment: If $L$ was completely distributive to start with, then adding a new top remains completely distributive.

Comment: But if not, not necessarily. So adding a new top to the lattice of regular open sets of $[0,1]$ remains a not completely distributive lattice. And one where the top element is join-irreducible. But the non distributive-compleateness is not due to what you'd like. Right?

Comment: Yes, precisely.